# How can I set next day if my alarm's time is past?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I must set the alarm to 10:35 even application created. But when I setted this time. My application firing alarm because date is past. I have to set 10:35. If date is past, I want to start next day at 10:35. How can I do that?

My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alarm.class);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 35);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 234, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: How exactly did you try the code you just added? Show where you have it in your original snippet.

Comment: I forget to erase  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); .So You are right.I deserve the duplicate.I am editting now.